# Installing Superset on Rancher

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher, apache-superset

I'm trying to create a superset instance in Rancher but it do not prompted me to a admin user creation and I cant get past through login. I already tried admin/admin but it shows me "login failed".
Is there any step that I'm skipping?

My .yml file is based in https://howchoo.com/kubernetes/how-to-install-apache-superset-on-a-gke-kubernetes-cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it without using helm.
I found this [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset) and was able to run superset properly after executing the commands that are in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the helm to install the superset on kubernetes cluster.

once you have updated the **values.yaml** file for the helm you can apply those changes.

Helm chat : https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/superset

in this helm init container setting up the user and database details :

```
initFile: |-
  /usr/local/bin/superset-init --username admin --firstname myfirstname --lastname mylastname --email admin@fab.org --password mypassword
  superset load_examples
  superset runserver
```

you can read the documentation in Github. You can set the password and username.

Comment: With helm is there a way we can deploy the superset without helm and with the yaml file only?